# Problems using Rubymine with WSL

Tags: ruby, rubymine, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I created a debian WSL. I installed Ruby and Rails and all the necessary stuff to make the rails server run.
Now I want to edit my code with Rubymine. What is the best way to accomplish my goal? 
Do I have to prepare path mapping and keep the files in sync? Or is there a better way like directly editing the code in debian file system?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under wsl you can access the windows filesystem via mount point. C: is under /mnt/c . So you could write your sourcecode with any windows-editor you like, but only in the windows filesystem. If you wonna start your rails app, go to the directory in the wsl:  `/mnt/c/Users/oliver/myrailsapp/`

Comment: Thank you very much :-)